# Is there a theory about time traveling without paradox or multiple universes?

Tags: time, paradox

If you think about time travel you will quickly come to problems like the time paradox. In order to avoid a solution of the question about the paradox, the theory of multiple universes is used. Is there an approach that works without the multiple universes and yet does not contain a time paradox?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Vague questions such as yours are not really suitable for our format and are best addressed by reading encyclopedias, e.g.[IEP's](https://www.iep.utm.edu/timetrav/) or [SEP's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time-travel/) Time Travel. We take more pointed questions that come up after that.

Comment: The question may be too speculative, but perhaps someone knows an answer that is not primarily a personal opinion. Although your question might be closed I hope you try again if that is the case. Best wishes and welcome to this SE!

Comment: You could check on physics.stackexchange.com.  There has been work on how time travel would work if it turned out to be possible.

Comment: This looks like a question for a physicist rather than a philosopher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Philosophy.SE!

Yes, there are several solutions.

## [Blinovitch Limitation Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinovitch_Limitation_Effect)

Coming from Doctor Who it states that if you try to contact with another instance of yourself, some kind of energy will stop you from doing it. Another aspect is that you cannot change your past decisions.

## [Novikov self-consistency principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle)

In short, it states that despite you can travel back in time, you cannot change past. Instead, you being a time traveller are the cause of given present which sometimes might look like causal loop: you can be a father of yourself, for example. Whether to count it as a paradox, is on you, though. There is a novel where the main character becomes both a father and a mother of himself, which is an example of it applied. Can't remember the title, however. Another example is when Harry Potter travels the time.

This answer might not be comprehensive, people could come by with other solutions and if there are any, let others answer.